# Mongodb $project with $multiply return null

Tags: mongodb, multiplication

I create a $project stage in my Mongodb Compass, in this stage I use $multiply to multiply a datafield with a number as in my screenshot. But why my result always return to null [My stage screenshot with null return for TotalScore data field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b4Zx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation work as pipeline so the result of this projection pipeline will give you hop1score field and you won't be able to access it in same operation. So, Either make one more projection or use cond operator as first argument of multiply operator.

Comment: Just add one more details that we have to use the '$' for each field in the next project stage